# How to mention custom expression in the view lable using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have a list. In that list Id and name are the key's. In the view I want to show both Id and name values. when select multiple options the values should be id's i.e.., id need to be assigned to ng-model.I tried below code.

**Eg:-**

```
ng-options="listRef.id as listRef.name for listRef in list"
 (Or)
ng-options="listRef.id as listRef.id for listRef in list"
```

In above code possible to show any one variable value but I want both id and name.and I tyried ng-repeat also but the problem is only one option selecting.I want multiple option selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use string concatenation there

```
ng-options="(listRef.name + ' ' + listRef.id) as listRef.id for listRef in list"
```